# Service Bus 1.0 Can't Create Queue or Topic

Tags: azure, appfabric, servicebus, windows-server-2012, azureservicebus

I've installed Service Bus for Windows Server on Server 2012. I'm trying to use the "Service Bus Explorer" management GUI to manage queues/topics.

I'm connecting to my service namespace by using the endpoint connection generated by the following PowerShell command:

```
Get-SBClientConfiguration -Namespaces 'MyNamespace' -Verbose;
```

Which generates:

```
Endpoint=sb://MyMachine/MyNamespace;StsEndpoint=https://MyMachine:9355/MyNamespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355
```

And I am able to connect successfully.

PROBLEM:

In the Service Bus Explorer GUI, when I try to create a queue or topic, I get the following error in the Log output:

```
Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've gone through every Service Bus 1.0 setup guide I could find and everything seems to be in order with my installation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the tool. In December I came across a similar problem:

If you GAC the Windows Azure Service Bus version of the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll v.1.8:

- The Service Bus Gateway and Service Bus Message Broker Windows services of Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server start correctly, but they load the cloud dll instead of the on-premises one.
- Any client application running on the same machine loads the cloud version of the dll.
- If a client application connects to a local, on-premises SB namespace, The NamespaceManager and MessagingFactory get created correctly.

  - namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
  - MessagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
- The NamespaceManager object can bed used to create and delete entities (e.g. queues)
- Instead, if the application tries to send or receive a message to/from a local queue with a MessageSender or MessageReceiver object created starting from the MessagingFactory, the operation fails and an exception (with 50002 error number) is catched by the application.
  After removing the Windows Azure Service Bus Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll v.1.8 from the GAC and after  restarting the Service Bus Gateway and Service Bus Message Broker Windows services, the problem disappears.
- The client application is able to send and receive messages to/from a local queue linking both the cloud and on-premises dlls.
  In a nutshell, if you GAC the cloud version of the dll, the Service Bus Gateway and Service Bus Message Broker Windows services start correctly, you can create messaging entities, but you get errors when an app tries to send/receive messages.

Questions:

- Did you GACed the Windows Azure version of the dll?
- What version of the Service Bus Explorer are you using (see the about form)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not see the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll in the GAC. (We've never had any version of Azure installed on this machine, only Service Bus 1.0). The Microsoft.Servicebus.dll version is 1.8.0.0 (used to compile SBE, was from the Service Bus NuGet package), and the Service Bus Explorer version (from the "About" form) is 1.8.0.0